# GmailApp.sendEmail Frequency Limit?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script using GmailApp.sendEmail which is sending out about 20 email per execution.  Manually running it, I only get 3 of the emails, and then running again sends nothing until approx 5 minutes later.

It seems there is a max of 3 mail send per script/user and maybe a max of 1 execution per 5 minutes, however there is absolutely nothing in the execution transcript.

This makes development hard, as you make a small change and have to wait 5 minutes, and also in production I would need it to process many emails.

It's already really unclear to me how the quota system works, and how you can see what you have left, however this is an extra level of uncertainty.

Comment: I don't believe there is a time limit on the sending side. There is a time limit of 60 emails per minute on *receiving* mail.

I regularly run scripts sending 1000+ emails in less than a minute without problems.

Are you using a verified domain account or free Gmail account?

It could also be something in your code so including that in your question would be a big help!

Comment: I just tested it by sending 90 of the same email to myself in batches. 84 of them delivered and the email report log shows that the remaining 6 are " 
In progress
The message could not be delivered at this time because the recipient's account is too busy." so you can check your admin log to see what exactly the problem is. I don't see how this makes development hard? surely if 1 sends you can be confident the rest will send unless you're very inexperienced with scripting or doing something very complex?

Comment: I know this thread is almost 5 years. I'm using GmailApp send mail too and encounter similar problem. I'm looking for the limit to send. I couldn't find a clear informattion. Google documentation that limit is 100 recepients per day. So I tried sending email to myself. I only receive one email. After a wait of few minutes I could send again. Now, I run a loop and make my email like this email+i@gmail.com where +i is  a loop variable. Interestingly all mail got send instantly to my address. But I still can't find a reliable source what is the limt. As I could send more than 100 email per day

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no frequency limit.

My test script was using a loop to send a message, and the message was the same, just 10 copies of the same thing.

Google is clearly clever enough to not send identical messages, although not clever enough as 2 or 3 do go.

If the script is re-run within about 5 minutes, it recognised them again as duplicates, so didn't send.

Introducing a count value and timestamp into the subject for example, meant that all emails were sent and received every time.

Comment: This is not an answer, you should reply in comments rather than as an answer.

Comment: The answer is that I was not being restricted by a limit, but another feature, which I was trying to describe for clarity.

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't think it is an answer.  It is clearly the answer to the question I asked, and may help someone with the same question who doesn't understand the behaviour they are seeing.